# Pretty print html output from Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, pretty-print

Is there any way to pretty print html output from Jekyll?

For example, below is a snippet of html that Jekyll generates. Notice how the `<p>` tags have no indentation and have unnecessary line breaks after them.

```
      ...
      <div id="content">

<p class="flush">Post 1</p>

<p class="flush">Post 2</p>

<p class="flush">Post 3</p>


      </div>
      ...
```

I'm imagining an option or plugin that would pretty print like this instead:

```
      ...
      <div id="content">
        <p class="flush">Post 1</p>
        <p class="flush">Post 2</p>
        <p class="flush">Post 3</p>
      </div>
      ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you to choose one of [tidy-makers](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=tidy) and write your own `:tidy` task in the end of jekyll-specific task chain. Or, even easier:

```
desc "Tidy jekyll output"
task :tidy do
  `find _site -name "*.html" -exec tidy {} \;`
end
```

Please note, that neither your newly created task nor any plugin that probably may be found over the internet will not be applied on *github pages*, since they have restricted policies to run jekyll.

Comment: Whast is "jekyll specific task chain"? is it custom plugin or custom build script ?